# How to print buckets available?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to print available buckets on AWS but failed. I tried multiple tutorials online and i would get `cannot locate credentials` and `'s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute` errors.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id = "Random",aws_secret_access_key = "Secret" )
client = s3.client('s3')
response = client.list_buckets()
print(response)
```

Comment: Did you create a service account in AWS and add permissionis in IAM ?

Comment: yes i did. I successfully updated the bucket and uploaded files from a django project but cannot read them @SukumarRdjf

Comment: can you please post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Side-note: It is not advisable to put Access Key and Secret Key in your code. Instead, if the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, simply assign an IAM Role to the instance. If the code is running on your own computer, store the credentials in a file by using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():

   print(bucket.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you are defining `s3` as a **resource:**

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

But then you are trying to use it as a client:

```
client = s3.client('s3')
```

That won't work. If you want a client, create one with:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
```

Or, you can extract a *client* from the *resource:*

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
response = s3_resource.meta.client.list_buckets()
```

Or, sticking with the resource, you can use:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
  # Do something with bucket
```

Confused? Try to stick with one method. **Client** directly matches the underlying API calls made to S3 and is the same as all other languages. **Resource** is a more "Pythonic" way of accessing resources. The calls get translated to client API calls. Resources can be a little more challenging when figuring out required permissions, since there isn't a one-to-one mapping to actual API call.